# Simple Java Program Isn't Getting Intended Output

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Player {

int att;
int str;
int def;
int hp;
int attackRoll;
int defenceRoll;
int maxHit;

//A player has variable attack, strength, defence, and hp stats
//attack = determines accuracy, strength = determines damage, defence = determines ability to block hits
public Player(int attack, int strength, int defence, int hitpoints)
{
    attack = att;
    strength = str;
    defence = def;
    hitpoints = hp;
    /*
        attackRoll and defenceRoll are used by the 2 players to determine probability
        of successfully scoring a hit, in m sample testing attRoll will always be
        higher than defRoll; they are integer numbers used in below method
    */
    attackRoll = (this.att + 3)*(90+64); 
    defenceRoll = (this.def + 3)*(0+64);
    maxHit = (int) ((0.5) + ((this.str + 0 + 8.0)*(86.0+64.0))/(640.0));
    //maxHit determines the maximum number player can deal each attack
}

//this determines if p1 successfully lands a hit on p2, true if so, false if not
//accuracy is calculated as a probability, ie  .7 probability of hitting
//in which case there is .7 probability of being true and .3 of being false
public static boolean hit(Player p1, Player p2)
{
    double accuracy;
    if (p1.attackRoll > p2.defenceRoll)
    {
        accuracy = 1.0 - ((double)(p2.defenceRoll+2.0)/(2*(p1.attackRoll+1.0)));
    }
    else
    {
        accuracy = (double) (p1.attackRoll/(2*(p2.defenceRoll+1.0)));
    }
    Random r = new Random();
    System.out.println("Accuracy: " + accuracy);
    return r.nextDouble() <= accuracy;
    //idea is that if accuracy is .7 for example, nextDouble() generates
    //between 0-1.0 so the probability that nextDouble() is <= .7 is .7, what we want
}

//calculates damage p1 does to p2, if hit returns true
public static void attack(Player attacker, Player defender)
{
    int damage = 0;
    if(!hit(attacker, defender)) return; //if the attacker missed, damage is 0, defender doesn't lose hp

    //if p1 successfully landed a hit on p2 as determined in previous method
    else if(hit(attacker, defender))
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        damage = r.nextInt(attacker.maxHit+1); //p1 deals (0 to maxHit) damage on p2 from that attack
        defender.hp -= damage; //p2 loses that much hp
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int p1wins = 0; //counts number of times p1 won
    int p2wins = 0; //counts number of times p2 won
    int firstCounter = 0; //counts the number of times p1 went first, should be near 50% as its randomly decided
    int secondCounter = 0; //couonts the number of times p2 went first, should be near 50%
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) //10000 trials of p1 and p2 battling
    {
        Player p1 = new Player(99, 99, 99, 99); //set p1's attack, strength, defence, hp to 99
        Player p2 = new Player(99, 99, 99, 40); //p2 only has 40 hp, therefore p2 should lose most of the time
        Random r = new Random();
        int first = r.nextInt(2); //determines which player attacks first
        if(first == 0) firstCounter++;
        if(first == 1) secondCounter++;
        while((p1.hp>0) && (p2.hp>0)) //the fight goes on until one player dies (hp is <= 0)
        {

            if(first == 0) //if player 1 attacks first
            {

                attack(p1, p2); //player 1 attacks player 2
                if(p2.hp <= 0) break; //if player 2's hp goes 0 or below from that attack, he dies and there's no more fighting
                attack(p2, p1); //then p2 attacks p1, and repeat
                if(p1.hp <= 0) break;
            }
            else if (first == 1) //if player  2 attacks first
            {

                attack(p2, p1); //player 2 attacks player 1
                if(p1.hp <= 0) break;
                attack(p1, p2);
                if(p2.hp <= 0) break;
            }

        }
          if(p1.hp <= 0) p2wins++; 
        else if(p2.hp <= 0) p1wins++;
    }
    System.out.println("p1 won " + p1wins + " times."); //prints number of times p1 wins
    System.out.println("p2 won " + p2wins + " times.");
    System.out.println(firstCounter); //prints number of times p1 went first, should be near 50% with large sample size
    System.out.println(secondCounter);
}
```

}

The above code is a program that simulates 2 players fighting.
The main idea is to understand that a player has 4 stats (attack, strength, defense, hp) and that if two players fight with the same stats (ie 99,99,99,99 both), then the probability that anyone will win is naturally about 50%.

The problem I'm encountering is that the program makes p2 win every single game, even with stats that are obviously vastly inferior

(ie p1 having 99 att, 99 str, 99 def, 99 hp   p2 having 99 att, 99 str, 99 def, but 20 hp), thus p2 would die much sooner in most trials, but a run of 10000 fights displays p2 winning all 10000 of them, which is obviously wrong and not intended. I can't figure out why p2 is winning 100% of the time.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error at the beginning of the Player constructor.

Assignments' order are wrong. The correct way is:

```
att = attack;
str = strength;
def = defence;
hp = hitpoints;
```

Otherwise, p1.hp and p2.hp are always 0.